# Error using pygame: "no module named locals"

Tags: python, pygame

I have been coding a window in pygame. My code starts with this:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
```

I get this error when I try to run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyg2.py", line 2, in <module>
     from pygame.locals import *
ImportError: No module named locals
```

Here is my full code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
   
    
def create_window():
    global window, window_height, window_width, window_title
    window_width, window_height = 800,600
    window_title = "WINXP Settings"
    pygame.display.set_caption(window_title)
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), 
pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
    
create_window()
    
    
isRunning = True
    
while isRunning:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            isRunning = False
    
    
    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    
    pygame.display.update()
    
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

My computer is linux lubuntu, not Windows XP, despite this line of code:

```
window_title = "WINXP Settings"
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a file named **pygame.py** in the **current directory** in which you are running the script. If so, change the **file's name** and try again.

Comment: i do, that is a good point, i'll try deleting it, since it is an empty python file anyway.

Comment: the problem is still promenent after deleting my file:     `pygame.py`

Comment: @FNaF_Master109 Well, then try to move your script into a different directory and reinstall pygame. Could also be that you accidentally installed pygame for python2 and not python3.